# Cannot install package via Miniconda: write permission

Tags: miniconda

I made a silent installation of Miniconda as root and then added write permission to a regular user, that cannot install packages:

If I try - as regular user:

```
conda install -y -c bioconda covtobed
```

I get this error:

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: /virome/tools/Miniconda_Shared
  uid: 1982
  gid: 1982
```

But the following commands work:

```
touch /virome/tools/Miniconda_Shared/test.write
touch /virome/tools/Miniconda_Shared/pkgs/test.write
rm /virome/tools/Miniconda_Shared/test.write /virome/tools/Miniconda_Shared/pkgs/test.write
```

What should I check (in terms of permission) to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/

```
sudo chgrp -R $SHAREDGROUP $PATHTOCONDA
sudo chmod 770 -R $PATHTOCONDA
```